# Recursive definition of a tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

I am working with graphs and I created my custom type called vertex.

```
type Vertex = (Int, [Vertex])
```

This type is a pair that takes `Int` which is an index number of a specific vertex and `[Vertex]` which is a list of vertices adjacent to this vertex.

Then I created an adjacency list of my graph. I ran into the problem though. How can I define that list of adjacent vertices for this given vertex type?

Let's I have a graph with two vertices. Let's call them **1** and **2**. There is an edge between them. So the vertex **1** is adjacent to the vertex **2** and vice versa.
Now, my adjacency list would look something like this:

```
adjacencyList :: [Vertex]
adjacencyList = [ (1, [ (2, [ (1, [ (2, [ (1, …) ]) ]) ]) ])
                , here would go the vertex 2 ]
```

So as you can see the problem is the recursive definition of my vertex type - vertex **1** has adjacent vertex **2** which has adjacent vertex **1** which has adjacent vertex **2** which has adjacent vertex **1** etc. This definition seems infinite to me.

In imperative languages like C++ I would solve this using pointers I guess.
But how can I overcome this problem in Haskell?

Comment: By the way, defining types like this with tuples is generally discouraged, because of type safety. Better to do `data Vertex = Vertex Int [Vertex]`.

Comment: I am still confused when to use `type` and when to use `data`. I understand custom type as a "synonym" to already existing type.

Comment: Also see https://wiki.haskell.org/Tying_the_Knot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why laziness is handy. You can just do

```
adjacencyList :: [Vertex]
adjacencyList = [a, b]
    where a = (1, [b])
          b = (2, [a])
```

This code might seem mysterious if you come from the c++ world. But, it's really nothing weirder than mutually recursive functions in c++. (In fact, the idea is almost the same.)

Comment: What if I want to create `adjacencyList` dynamically with unknown number of vertices beforehand?

Comment: @Superian007 If you want to do that, it really depends on what kind of data you're starting with.

Comment: I have a list representing game board. On this game board are black and white stones which both forms graphs. Every color has its own graph. So black stones have its own adjacency list and white stones has its own adjacency list.

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd to me that each vertex should be responsible for knowing about its neighbors. This style might work for C++ or other languages which use reference equality, but it's really awkward in Haskell.

Try to model your graph like this instead:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

type Vertex = Int
type Graph = Map Vertex [Vertex] -- each vertex mapped to its 'out-neighbors'
```

Then you don't need to build those complicated adjacency lists. Getting the neighbors of any vertex is simple:

```
neighbors :: Vertex -> Graph -> [Vertex]
neighbors v g = fromMaybe [] (Map.lookup v g)
```

The key is that every `Vertex` labeled `1` is the same `Vertex` whether or not it is the same object in memory.

In order to add connections, we can use the `insertWith` function from `Data.Map` with list append:

```
connect :: Vertex -> [Vertex] -> Graph -> Graph
connect = Map.insertWith (++)
```

And of course, we need to be able to create an empty graph:

```
empty :: Graph
empty = Map.empty
```

Keep in mind that this is for a directed graph. An undirected graph needs some additional care to preserve its invariants. Also, using lists for the adjacent vertices means that we can have multiple edges from a vertex to another vertex. We could use Sets instead to remove this behavior.

I hope this helps.